# Hedera - Token Service - Smart Contract ERC721 NFT - How do I get my contract to show in token associations?

Tags: smartcontracts, nft, erc721, hedera-hashgraph

I am trying to understand a bit more about the use of ERC721 contracts on Hedera and how they work with the Hedera Token Service (HTS).

If I use this contract [ERC721Mock.sol](https://github.com/hashgraph/hedera-smart-contracts/blob/main/contracts/erc-721/ERC721Mock.sol), would the tokens I created show up in the Token Associations correctly?

I'm not sure if using the Smart Contracts or the HTS directly in code is a better solution.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Hedera network, you have two options when it comes to create NFT. You can either use Hedera Token Service (HTS) or deploy traditional ERC721 on Hedera Smart Contract Service.

HTS is special as it requires users to associate to tokens before they can start interacting with the tokens so once you associate the tokens, it will appear on your token list. ERC721, on the other hand, is running on Smart Contract Service so you don't need to associate the token when using it and as a result it will not show on your token list.